# I can't disconnect the bot from the voice chat (discord)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, disnake

There is a problem with the bot that when executing the "leave" command (see below) the bot does not exit the voice chat. The first command works stably, but the second one, when executed, the bot unsubscribes that it has left the voice chat, but does not do so

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("First, go to the voice chat")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.voice_client):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I left the voice chat")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am not in voice chat")
```

I tried changing bool, removing if and else conditions

Comment: Update your `discord.py` version. (Right now *version 2.2.2* is out)

Comment: Yes, but I'm writing code using the disnake library

Comment: Um, I don't know what happened. I didn't change or touch anything, but for some reason the team started working as it should)))

Comment: The team ? Does your code work the way you expected now ?

Comment: Command* Yes, everything works. It remains to learn how to turn on music through the bot. And make him commands: stop and play